# Writing unit tests when using aiohttp and asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am updating one of my Python packages so it is asynchronous (using `aiohttp` instead of `requests`). I am also updating my unit tests so they work with the new asynchronous version, but I'm having some trouble with this.

Here is a snippet from my package:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    while True:
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                assert response.status == 200
                return await response.json()
        except Exception as error:
            pass


class FPL():
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    async def get_user(self, user_id, return_json=False):
        url = API_URLS["user"].format(user_id)
        user = await fetch(self.session, url)

        if return_json:
            return user
        return User(user, session=self.session)
```

which all seems to be working when used so:

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         fpl = FPL(session)
         user = await fpl.get_user(3808385)
         print(user)

loop = asynio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

>>> User 3808385
```

Unfortunately I am having some trouble with my unit tests. I thought I could simply do something like

```
def _run(coroutine):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coroutine)


class FPLTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.fpl = FPL(session)

    def test_user(self):
        user = _run(self.fpl.get_user("3523615"))
        self.assertIsInstance(user, User)

        user = _run(self.fpl.get_user("3523615", True))
        self.assertIsInstance(user, dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

it gives errors such as

```
DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function loop=loop)
```

and

```
ResourceWarning: Unclosed client session <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fbe647fd208>
```

I've tried adding a `_close()` function to the `FPL` class that closes the session, and then calling this from the tests, but this also doesn't work and still says there is an unclosed client session.

Is it possible to do this and am I simply doing something wrong, or am I better off using something like `asynctest`or `pytest-aiohttp` instead?

EDIT: I've also checked `aiohttp`'s documentation and found an [example](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html#unittest) showing how to test applications with the standard library’s unittest. Unfortunately I can't get it to work, since `loop` provided in `AioHTTPTestCase` has been deprecated since 3.5 and is throwing an error:

```
class FPLTest(AioHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.fpl = FPL(session)

    @unittest_run_loop
    async def test_user(self):
        user = await self.fpl.get_user("3523615")
        self.assertIsInstance(user, User)

        user = await self.fpl.get_user("3523615", True)
        self.assertIsInstance(user, dict)
```

gives

```
tests/test_fpl.py:20: DeprecationWarning: The object should be created from async function
  session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
  ...
======================================================================
ERROR: test_user (__main__.FPLTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amos/Documents/fpl/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/test_utils.py", line 477, in new_func
    return self.loop.run_until_complete(
AttributeError: 'FPLTest' object has no attribute 'loop'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_user (__main__.FPLTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amos/Documents/fpl/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/test_utils.py", line 451, in tearDown
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.tearDownAsync())
AttributeError: 'FPLTest' object has no attribute 'loop'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use pytest with [aiohttp-pytest](https://github.com/aio-libs/pytest-aiohttp):

```
async def test_test_user(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         fpl = FPL(session)
         user = await fpl.get_user(3808385)
    assert isinstance(user, User)
```

Proverb of the modern python developer: life is too short not to use pytest.

You'll likely also want to setup a mock server to receive your http requests during tests, I don't have a trivial example, but a full working example can be seen [here](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/nosht/blob/master/py/tests/conftest.py#L78).

Comment: I quickly used this example to see if it would work, and it does - thanks! I was hoping I wouldn't have to convert all my tests and could continue using unittest, but I guess I will try out pytest (never used it before).

Comment: You don't have to convert all your tests, only the ones which require async behaviour. `pytest` runs standard unittest styles tests absolutely fine.

Comment: Also, switching from unittest to py.test is much like switching from urllib2 to requests - such an improvement that one never looks back and only regrets not doing the switch sooner!

Comment: I agree, it's really great so far. In the end I created some fixtures which allow me to access e.g. the `fpl` object in my tests. It didn't even take that long to convert everything and it looks much cleaner than before.